# DataBase Schema File (.sql file ) Download with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, php-7

Schenario :
   1) suppose that i have a database called myDataBase
   2) Assume that myDataBase have some tables like A,B,C,D
   3) i have to download the schema of the table A,B from the database with name myDataBase

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Do you have any question about this?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have done the migration of all the table of your project . If you are using a xampp server then goto http://localhost/phpmyadmin and select your database and then goto export tab on the top tab bar and simply export with go button

Comment: i know it by PhpMyAdmin GUI  ,But  i want it to be downloaded at runtime using either  laravel  or Php5+ Code

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    //ENTER THE RELEVANT INFO BELOW
    $mysqlUserName      = "root";
    $mysqlPassword      = "";
    $mysqlHostName      = "localhost";
    $DbName             = "ukkoteknik";
    $backup_name        = "mybackup.sql";
    $tables             = array("admin", "sample");

    Export_Database($mysqlHostName,$mysqlUserName,$mysqlPassword,$DbName,  $tables, $backup_name=false );

    function Export_Database($host,$user,$pass,$name,  $tables=false, $backup_name=false )
    {
        $mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$name);
        $mysqli->select_db($name);
        $mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

        $queryTables    = $mysqli->query('SHOW TABLES');
        while($row = $queryTables->fetch_row())
        {
            $target_tables[] = $row[0];
        }
        if($tables !== false)
        {
            $target_tables = array_intersect( $target_tables, $tables);
        }
        foreach($target_tables as $table)
        {
            $result         =   $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
            $fields_amount  =   $result->field_count;
            $rows_num=$mysqli->affected_rows;
            $res            =   $mysqli->query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table);
            $TableMLine     =   $res->fetch_row();
            $content        = (!isset($content) ?  '' : $content) . "\n\n".$TableMLine[1].";\n\n";

            for ($i = 0, $st_counter = 0; $i < $fields_amount;   $i++, $st_counter=0)
            {
                while($row = $result->fetch_row())
                { //when started (and every after 100 command cycle):
                    if ($st_counter%100 == 0 || $st_counter == 0 )
                    {
                            $content .= "\nINSERT INTO ".$table." VALUES";
                    }
                    $content .= "\n(";
                    for($j=0; $j<$fields_amount; $j++)
                    {
                        $row[$j] = str_replace("\n","\\n", addslashes($row[$j]) );
                        if (isset($row[$j]))
                        {
                            $content .= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $content .= '""';
                        }
                        if ($j<($fields_amount-1))
                        {
                                $content.= ',';
                        }
                    }
                    $content .=")";
                    //every after 100 command cycle [or at last line] ....p.s. but should be inserted 1 cycle eariler
                    if ( (($st_counter+1)%100==0 && $st_counter!=0) || $st_counter+1==$rows_num)
                    {
                        $content .= ";";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $content .= ",";
                    }
                    $st_counter=$st_counter+1;
                }
            } $content .="\n\n\n";
        }
        //$backup_name = $backup_name ? $backup_name : $name."___(".date('H-i-s')."_".date('d-m-Y').")__rand".rand(1,11111111).".sql";
        $date = date("Y-m-d");
        $backup_name = $backup_name ? $backup_name : $name.".$date.sql";
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");
        header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$backup_name."\"");
        //echo $content; exit;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

### DB only structure get in API response without export as (.sql)

#### Route

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1/db-migration', 'middleware'=>'auth:api'], function (){
    Route::post('server-db-structure-backup', [DBController::class, 'serverDBStructureBackup']);
});
```

#### DB Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\DBMigration;

use App\Traits\ApiResponser;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Facades\Modules\DBMigration\DBBackup\DBBackupFacade;

class DBController extends Controller
{
    use ApiResponser;

    public function serverDBStructureBackup()
    {
        try {

            $database = config('app.db');
            $user = config('app.dbuser');
            $pass = config('app.dbpass');
            $host = config('app.dbhost');



            $tableViewsCounts = DB::select('SELECT count(TABLE_NAME) AS TOTALNUMBEROFTABLES FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = ?', [$database]);
            $tableViewsCounts = $tableViewsCounts[0]->TOTALNUMBEROFTABLES;

            $viewsCounts = DB::select('SELECT count(TABLE_NAME) AS TOTALNUMBEROFVIEWS FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE  TABLE_TYPE LIKE "VIEW" AND TABLE_SCHEMA = ?', [$database]);
            $viewsCounts = $viewsCounts[0]->TOTALNUMBEROFVIEWS;

            $tablesCount = $tableViewsCounts-$viewsCounts;


            $proceduresCounts = DB::select('SELECT count(TYPE) AS proceduresCounts FROM mysql.proc WHERE  TYPE="PROCEDURE" AND db = ?', [$database]);
            $proceduresCounts = $proceduresCounts[0]->proceduresCounts;

            $functionsCounts = DB::select('SELECT count(TYPE) AS functionsCounts FROM mysql.proc WHERE  TYPE="FUNCTION" AND db = ?', [$database]);
            $functionsCounts = $functionsCounts[0]->functionsCounts;

            $projectURL = url('/');
            $deviceIP = \Request::ip();

            $all_table_create_statement =  DBBackupFacade::all_table_create_statement(['database'=>$database, 'newline' => '<newline><newline>']);
            $all_view_create_statement =  DBBackupFacade::all_view_create_statement(['database'=>$database, 'newline' => '<newline><newline>']);
            $all_procedure_create_statement =  DBBackupFacade::all_procedure_function_create_statement(['database'=>$database, 'newline' => '<newline><newline>', 'ROUTINE_TYPE' => 'PROCEDURE']);
            $all_function_create_statement =  DBBackupFacade::all_procedure_function_create_statement(['database'=>$database, 'newline' => '<newline><newline>', 'ROUTINE_TYPE' => 'FUNCTION']);


            $data = $database.' Database Backup Generated time = '.YmdTodmYPm(\Carbon\Carbon::now()).
                            '<newline>Project URL = '.$projectURL.
                            '<newline>Device IP = '.$deviceIP.

                            '<newline><newline>=============Objects Counting Start================= '.
                            '<newline>=============Objects Counting Start================= '.
                            '<newline>Total Tables + Views = '.$tableViewsCounts.
                            '<newline>Total Tables = '.$tablesCount.
                            '<newline>Total Views = '.$viewsCounts.
                            '<newline>Total Procedures = '.$proceduresCounts.
                            '<newline>Total Functions = '.$functionsCounts.
                            '<newline>=============Objects Counting End================= '.
                            '<newline>=============Objects Counting End================= '.

                            '<newline><newline>=============Table Structure Start================= '.
                            '<newline>=============Table Structure Start================= '.
                            '<newline><newline>SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; '.
                            '<newline>SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";'.
                            '<newline>START TRANSACTION;'.
                            '<newline>SET time_zone = "+06:00";'.
                            '<newline>drop database if exists '.$database.';'.
                            '<newline>CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS '.$database.' DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;'.
                            '<newline>use '.$database.';'.

                            '<newline><newline><newline>-- Total Tables = '.$tablesCount.
                            $all_table_create_statement.  // all tables create statement will store here

                            '<newline><newline><newline>SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;'.
                            '<newline>COMMIT;'.
                            '<newline><newline>=============Table Structure end================= '.
                            '<newline>=============Table Structure end================= '.

                            '<newline><newline>=============View Structure Start================= '.
                            '<newline>=============View Structure Start================= '.

                            '<newline><newline><newline>-- Total Views = '.$viewsCounts.
                            $all_view_create_statement.  // all views create statement will store here
                            '<newline><newline>=============View Structure end================= '.
                            '<newline>=============View Structure end================= '.

                            '<newline><newline>=============Procedure Structure Start================= '.
                            '<newline>=============Procedure Structure Start================= '.
                            '<newline><newline><newline>-- Total Procedures = '.$proceduresCounts.
                            $all_procedure_create_statement.  // all procedures create statement will store here
                            '<newline><newline>=============Procedure Structure end================= '.
                            '<newline>=============Procedure Structure end================= '.

                            '<newline><newline>=============Function Structure Start================= '.
                            '<newline>=============Function Structure Start================= '.
                            '<newline><newline><newline>-- Total Functions = '.$functionsCounts.
                            $all_function_create_statement.  // all functions create statement will store here
                            '<newline><newline>=============Function Structure end================= '.
                            '<newline>=============Function Structure end================= '

                            ;


            return $this->set_response([
                'instructions' => [
                    'search <newline> and then replace with batch enter',
                    'search (backslash n) and then replace with batch enter ',
                    'search (") and then replace with only double quote ',
                    'search (backslash r) and then replace with empty string ',
                ],
                'data' => $data
            ],  200,'success', ['DB Backup']);
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        }
    }

}
```

#### DB Facade Helper

```
<?php

namespace App\Facades\Modules\DBMigration\DBBackup;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


class DBBackupHelper
{

    public function all_table_create_statement($params=[])
    {
        $database = $params['database'] ?? '';
        $newline = $params['newline'] ?? '';

        $tables = DB::select('SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = ? and table_type="BASE TABLE"', [$database])
                  ;

        $str = '';
        foreach ($tables as $key => $table)
        {
            $table_name = $database.'.'.$table->table_name;
            $table_create_statement = ((array) DB::select('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table_name)[0])['Create Table'].';';
            $str.= isset($newline) ? $newline.$table_create_statement : $table_create_statement;
        }
        return $str;
    }

    public function all_view_create_statement($params=[])
    {
        $database = $params['database'] ?? '';
        $newline = $params['newline'] ?? '';

        $views = DB::select('SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = ? and table_type="VIEW"', [$database]);

        $str = '';
        foreach ($views as $key => $item)
        {
            $view_name = $database.'.'.$item->table_name;
            $view_create_statement = ((array) DB::select('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$view_name)[0])['Create View'].';';
            $str.= isset($newline) ? $newline.$view_create_statement : $view_create_statement;
        }
        return $str;
    }

    public function all_procedure_function_create_statement($params=[])
    {
        $database = $params['database'] ?? '';
        $newline = $params['newline'] ?? '';
        $ROUTINE_TYPE = $params['ROUTINE_TYPE'] ?? '';

        $prefix_proc_func =  '<newline>DELIMITER $$<newline>';
        $postfix_proc_func = '$$'.
                             '<newline>DELIMITER ;<newline>';

        $list = DB::select('
                            SELECT
                                r.ROUTINE_NAME routine_name,
                                CONCAT("CREATE ", r.ROUTINE_TYPE, " ", r.ROUTINE_NAME, group_concat(" (",p.PARAMETER_MODE, " ", p.PARAMETER_NAME, " ", p.DATA_TYPE," ) "), r.ROUTINE_DEFINITION) AS create_statement
                            FROM
                                information_schema.ROUTINES r
                                LEFT JOIN information_schema.PARAMETERS p ON r.SPECIFIC_NAME = p.SPECIFIC_NAME
                            WHERE
                            r.ROUTINE_SCHEMA = ?  AND r.ROUTINE_TYPE = ?
                            group by r.ROUTINE_NAME', [$database, $ROUTINE_TYPE]);


        $str = '';
        foreach ($list as $key => $item)
        {
            $routine_name = $item->routine_name;
            $create_statement = $item->create_statement;
            $drop_statement = 'DROP '.$ROUTINE_TYPE.' IF EXISTS  '.$routine_name.';<newline> $$<newline>';
            $create_statement= isset($newline) ? $newline.$create_statement : $routine_definition;

            $str .= $prefix_proc_func.$drop_statement.$create_statement.$postfix_proc_func;
        }
        return $str;
    }

}
```

#### Before Text response usage text modification instruction

- search **()** and then replace with batch enter
- search **(\n)** and then replace with batch enter
- search **(")** and then replace with only double quote (")
- search **(\r)** and then replace with empty string (")